# How to initialise class attributes?

Tags: python

I currently have the following two ways:

```
class Venue:
    store = Database.store()
    ids = [vid for vid in store.find(Venue.id, Venue.type == "Y")]

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

OR

```
class Venue:

    @classmethod
    def set_venue_ids(cls):
        store = Database.store()
        cls.ids = [vid for vid in store.find(Venue.id, Venue.type == "Y")]

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

And before using/instantiating the class I would call:

```
Venue.set_venue_ids()
```

What would be the correct way of achieving this?

If it's the first way, what would I do if the instantiation of the attribute required more complex logic that could be done more simply through the use of a function?

Or is there an entirely different way to structure my code to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want this attributes to be class attributes instead of instance attributes?

Comment: @valentjedi In my actual code, every venue object will need to access this list to do checks against.

Comment: @Giri So, can this param be an argument in some loop?

Comment: I understand it's "just an example" but as far as I'm concerned it's a pretty bad one - if you have values coming from a database, use a classmethod to  get those values each time you need them - else you'll quickly be out of sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely technical POV, a class is an instance of its metaclass so the metaclass initializer is an obvious candidate for class attributes initialization (at least when you have anything a bit complex).

Now given the canonical lifetime of a class object (usually the whole process), I would definitly *not* use an attribute here - if anyone adds or removes venues from your database while your process is running, your `ids` attributes will get out of sync. Why don't you use a `classmethod` instead to make sure your data are always have up to date ?

Oh and yes, another way to construct your `Venue.ids` (or any other class attribute requiring non-trivial code) without having complex code at the class top-level polluthing the class namespace (did you noticed that in your first example `store` becomes a class attributes too, as well as `vid` if using Python 2.x ?) is to put the code in a plain function and call that function from within your class statement's body, ie:

```
def list_venue_ids():
    store = Database.store()
    # I assume `store.find()` returns some iterator (not a `list`)
    # if it does return a list, you could just
    # `return store.find(...)`.    
    return list(store.find(Venue.id, Venue.type == "Y"))

class Venue(object):
    ids = list_venue_ids()
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

Comment: Essentially I would be looping through a list of venue objects, checking whether the venue object was in the list or not, performing some actions and then moving on to the next venue. Even if I used a method to ensure the list was up to date, could an instance not arise where a particular venue was removed from the database AFTER I had processed it in the loop? I am using this program to run a report and if what I described did occur, I would have to re-run the program as the report would now be incorrect.

Comment: @Giri of course if it's not a long running process the staled data issues is not taht much of an issue ;-) - but then what's the point of having this list as an attribute of your `Venue` class actually ?

Comment: Well I felt that if all instances would be using the list, maybe I should keep it within the class. The actual name of the class would most likely not be "Venue". I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way of writing my existing code using OOP concepts although I'm finding it tough to figure out how to separate things into appropriate classes.

Comment: How to properly separate responsabilities is indeed one of the difficult parts in OOD/OOP and one of the common mistakes is often to put too many responsabilities on a same class. It doesn't mean your design is actually wrong FWIW, it's a matter of context, but "A uses B" does not necessarily imply that "A owns B".